# Updated \l_file_search_path_seq (expl3) no longer recognises `~` (TeX Live 2023 updated yesterday)

Tags: expl3, latex3, texinputs, texlive-2023

[This question is an erroneous version of [(Corrected) updated \l_file_search_path_seq (expl3) no longer recognises `~` (TeX Live 2023 updated yesterday)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698241/).]

After updating TeX Live 2023 using `tlmgr` yesterday, the following code no longer works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_file_search_path_seq { ~/path/to/some/place }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_file_input: { \file_input:n {subdirectory/filename} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \myinput \my_file_input:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\myinput
\end{document}
```

Specifically, `subdirectory/filename` is not found,

```
! LaTeX Error: File 'subdirectory/filename' not found.
```

`~/path/to/some/place/subdirectory/filename.tex` exists. Last week, `pdflatex` found it without any trouble.

If I replace `~` in `~/path/to/some/place` by the path to my home directory, the file is found. However, earlier TeX Live (both 2023 prior to update and earlier versions) did not require this. To check, I compiled the same code with `pdflatex` from TeX Live 2022 and the file was found fine.

Is this expected? Is there any way to restore the old behaviour? I would prefer not to hardcode the path to my home directory if I can avoid it because not doing so makes things more portable.

Comment: No idea what's changed. A guess is that you could try `\c_tilde_str` in your path there.

Comment: `~` has been a space in `expl3` context since day one: I can't see how this could ever have worked. That said, can KI check the current `expl3` release you have, and do you have any idea of the version you had previously?

Comment: @gusbrs That would be I think my answer - putting the expanded string into the `seq`.

Comment: @JosephWright That was just a quick hunch. Given the question, I'd say an authoritative answer would be best.  ;-)

Comment: What happens  in tl22 if you do not add the path/to/someplace to the search path. Is the file then not found?

Comment: I wonder if there was something else changing the catcode of `~` in the context you were using it ... it's the only reason I can think this might have worked in the past

Comment: @JosephWright Very sorry. I was sure I tested this because I was surprised it wasn't too minimal. I'll ask another question rather than invalidate egreg's answer. Let me know if I should delete this. (If there were no answers I'd delete or edit.)

Comment: @cfr A new question sounds good to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way the code could have worked before the update and, indeed, I tested it with no update since a few days, but also with TeX Live 2022 and earlier.

The only way to make the code work is to use

```
\seq_put_right:Nx \l_file_search_path_seq { \c_tilde_str/path/to/some/place }
```

so a tilde with a “safe” category code is used. If you have non ASCII bits in the path, you can do

```
\seq_put_right:Nx \l_file_search_path_seq { \c_tilde_str \exp_not:n { /path/to/some/place } }
```

for extra safety.

Comment: You're completely correct, of course. I'll ask a new question.