# (Corrected) updated \l_file_search_path_seq (expl3) no longer recognises `~` (TeX Live 2023 updated yesterday)

Tags: expl3, latex3, texinputs, texlive-2023

[This is an amended version of [Updated \l_file_search_path_seq (expl3) no longer recognises `~` (TeX Live 2023 updated yesterday)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698201/), which isn't the question I needed to ask.]

After updating TeX Live 2023 using `tlmgr` yesterday, the following code no longer works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_input_add:n 
{
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_file_search_path_seq { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_file_input: { \file_input:n {ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \myinput \my_file_input:
\cs_new_eq:NN \myinputadd \my_input_add:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\myinputadd{~/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau}

\begin{document}
\myinput
\end{document}
```

Specifically, `ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello` is not found,

```
!! LaTeX Error: File 'ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.138 \myinput
```

`~//Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello.tex` exists. Last week, `pdflatex` found it without any trouble.

If I replace `~` in `~/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau` by the path to my home directory, the file is found. However, earlier TeX Live (both 2023 prior to update and earlier versions) did not require this. To check, I compiled the same code with `pdflatex` from TeX Live 2022 and the file was found fine.

[image: file found prior to update]

Is this expected? Is there any way to restore the old behaviour? I would prefer not to hardcode the path to my home directory if I can avoid it because not doing so makes things more portable.

## EDIT

Here's an example which shows `\input` works with `~`, but `\myinput` fails, whereas both compile successfully with older TeX Live.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_input_add:n 
{
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l_file_search_path_seq { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \my_file_input: { \file_input:n {ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello} }
\cs_new_eq:NN \myinput \my_file_input:
\cs_new_eq:NN \myinputadd \my_input_add:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\myinputadd{~/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau}

\begin{document}
\input{~/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello}
\myinput
\end{document}
```

Here's the log file from successful compilation with TeX Live 2022. Specifically, I used `TEXMFHOME=/d /usr/local/texlive/bin.2022/pdflatex prawf` to compile.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.11.12)  11 OCT 2023 14:44
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**prawf
(./prawf.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01>
L3 programming layer <2022-11-02>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-10-26 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(./prawf.aux)
\openout1 = `prawf.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.

(/home/cfr/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact
/hello.tex)
(/home/cfr/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact
/hello.tex) [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./praw
f.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 439 strings out of 474971
 8992 string characters out of 5776128
 349853 words of memory out of 5000000
 22017 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,5n,38p,179b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr1
0.pfb>
Output written on prawf.pdf (1 page, 11187 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Here's the log with current TeX Live 2023 and compilation failure. Specifically, I used `TEXMFHOME=/d pdflatex prawf` to compile.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.10.10)  11 OCT 2023 14:47
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**prawf
(./prawf.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(./prawf.aux)
\openout1 = `prawf.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 137.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 137.

(/home/cfr/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact
/hello.tex)

! LaTeX Error: File 'ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello' not found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.139 \myinput
              
? 
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./prawf.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 441 strings out of 474934
 9046 string characters out of 5759816
 1917791 words of memory out of 5000000
 22064 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 35i,5n,50p,180b,107s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>

Output written on prawf.pdf (1 page, 11181 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

The same example compiles successfully with `pdflatex` from TeX Live 2021 and TeX Live 2020. For TeX Live 2019, `\input` fails but the `\file_input:n` case compiles if `\usepackage{expl3}` is enable `expl3` syntax.

Comment: does `\input{~//Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello}` work?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In the main body of the document? Yes. So does `\input{~/Dogfennau/Fy_Ysgrifau/dysgu/ymresymiadau/ysgrifennu-LEARN-compact/hello}`.

Comment: well I can reproduce that it doesn't work, you would need something like `\myinputadd{\string~/Documents}` to get a string tilde, but I can not reproduce some new change, it fails for me on texlive 2022 too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's very odd. Why would it work for me? And it has worked very consistently for me for quite some time. (At least, the more complicated real version has.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I add `\seq_show:N \l_file_search_path_seq`, I get the same sequence with both current TL and 2022, so whatever is different happens after that. I'm also using `TEXMFHOME=/d`, so it isn't something in `TEXMFHOME`. (Or shouldn't be.)

Comment: well perhaps you (or some package you used) changed the catcode of the tilde to 12, e.g. this would work ``\catcode`~=12 \myinputadd{~/Documents}``.

Comment: Do not forget: you have no proof, that your short example ever worked, you know this only for your "more complicated real version".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Exactly the code I posted compiles with TL 2022 and not current TL. So I really don't see how it could be that, especially since I'm taking `TEXMFHOME` out of it. And I do have proof this short example works with TL 2022. I test it and it compiles.

Comment: if your example compiles with tl2022, show the log-file.

Comment: I would have expected you to need `\string~` or some expl3 code to `_str` the input otherwise `~` will expand to a non breaking space construct

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Please see above. I used an example with both `\input` and `\myinput` for comparison and included logs for both TL 2022 and 2023. TL 2022 finds the file in both cases, but TL 2023 now finds the file only for the `\input` case and `\myinput` fails. I've also included the exact commands I'm using to compile, just to show it isn't some strange thing in `TEXMFHOME`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see edit above for logs from the working (2022) and non-working (current 2023) case. But `\input{~/...}` works in both cases. Only the `\myinput` case now fails.

Comment: I'll see if I can re-create the filepath and recreate later but I can't see how it ever worked if `~` is `\nobreakspace {}`  unless you make it `\protected` somewhere

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I can reproduce it now. In tl 22 `\tl_to_str:n {~/Documents}` was used, and now the tilde is expanded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh, so reverting to texlive 2020 behaviour (but I don't see this,odd...)